# hello! how do i create a gap between my tags and the bottom of the page? (tumblr)

Tags: html, tumblr

sorry i dont really know how to use this site, ive never been on here (and im completely useless at html), but my URL is  and if you scroll down it's fine, but if you go to a page, for instance , there isnt a gap between the bottom of the post and the bottom of the page, and i'd really like for there one to be.

this is the code

Answer (score 0):

In your tumblr theme, add the following CSS rule:

```
#wrapper #content .post {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
#wrapper #content {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

And it will be like this:

```
 #wrapper #content {
           margin-bottom: 50px;
           {block:if400px} width: 420px;   {/block:if400px}
            {block:if450px} width: 470px;   {/block:if450px}
           {block:if500px} width: 520px;  {/block:if500px}
           {block:if250px} width: 270px;   {/block:if250px}
            float: right; 
        }
```